# Extjs 4 create toolbar items width ajax request

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have to create a toolbar that calculates its items from an ajax request. look at both functions initComponent and buildItems, I don't get the same result of toolbar.items elements, even the run of ajax request done correctly as you see in the builsItems method after calling console.log. 
please Help (I am beginner, I am using Extjs 4) Thanks a lot.

```
Ext.define('Dev.view.layout.Toolbarapp',{
   extend:'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
   alias :'widget.toolbarapp',
   border:false,
   height:35,
   initComponent:function(){
           this.items=[];
           Ext.Ajax.disableCaching=false;
           Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url : '/gdev/jsontest',
                        callback:this.buildItems,       
                        scope:this
           });  
       console.log(this.items); //THE RESULT IS []    
       this.callParent(arguments);
   },   
   buildItems:function(options, sucess, response){      
        if (sucess==true) {
            var listItems=[];
            var applist=Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            Ext.each(applist, function(rec){
                   listItems.push({'text'     :rec.appid,
                                   'iconCls'  :rec.iconcls,
                                   'operation':rec.appcode
                                  }
                                );                     
                 });
            this.items=listItems;   
            console.log(this.items); //THE RESULT IS [Object { text=100,      
    iconCls="appsysadmin", operation="appsysadmin"}, Object { text=101, 
    iconCls="appmailxe", operation="appmailxe"}]
        }
        else {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error','not found');
        }

   }
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

Assigning object notation components to *this.items* only works before the callParent in initComponent.

After that, the items are already initialised, ext won't pick up changes to it. You should use the Toolbar component's [add method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar-method-add) instead.

In your buildItems method, rather than building an array, simply call add with your object notation component:

```
var me = this;
Ext.each(applist, function(rec){
                   me.add({'text'     :rec.appid,
                                   'iconCls'  :rec.iconcls,
                                   'operation':rec.appcode
                                  }
                                );                     
                 });
```

I haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure that's how I did it (from top of my head)

Edit: added me variable for scope

Comment: I did it, but I get the error : this.add is not a function. It's logical, because this inside each means scope changed, so I declared before Ext.each a variable like the following : var listitems=this, and i replaced this.add by listitems.add. everything works fine. SO VERY THANKS GUY.

Comment: @ora-271071. Yes, fair point. That's a scope issue. this means something else within the each callback. The extjs way is usually to create a _me_ variable and assign this to it, then me is available within any nested function. I've amended the code.

Comment: @ora-271071. You should accept one of the answers as well (the tick mark on the left hand side of one of the answers)

Answer (score 2):

Why not take advantage of the component loader? See: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/component-loader/component-loader.html

Comment: Very thanks for your participation. in fact, it's a great idea to user implicit ajax request for the component (in the future I'll plan to use this feature). but for now, the answer number 1 corresponding my need it's exacltly what I want. VERY THANKS GUY FOR YOUR ANSWER.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `console.log` call is outside of your callback, and therefore it gets called before the Ajax request ever completes.

With your second `console.log` call, it's being called inside the callback... which is initiated after the Ajax request has finished. Basically, you need to do all of your work in your callback if you're expecting to use data returned from the Ajax request.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question